# How to rappel with a dog?

Tags: rappelling, dogs

My wife and I are planning a camping and climbing trip and we would likely need to rappel with our medium-sized (45lbs/20kg) dog. Holding the dog is obviously unacceptable, and using the dog's backpack is also unacceptable due to the flimsiness of the straps and buckles.

Simply from a technical perspective, and assuming the dog is capable and isn't traumatically afraid of heights (she's basically a mountain goat in a dog disguise), what equipment would I use to rappel with a dog? Would it be similar to [rappelling with a child](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/7982/how-to-tandem-rappel-abseil-with-a-child) (except with a dog-specific harness, of course)?

Comment: Related sister site question [How would I get my dog down from our 3rd floor bedroom if there was a fire?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6504/how-would-i-get-my-dog-down-from-our-3rd-floor-bedroom-if-there-was-a-fire)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your dog needs a climbing harness:

[image]

I have a friend who goes *everywhere* with their dog, and they have a pro-rated harness for them. You need to get your dog a harness, and tandem rappel with them just like you would another person, or with a heavy gear bag, by clipping them into the same point on your harness as your device.

[REI sells dog climbing harnesses:](https://www.rei.com/product/796351/ruffwear-doubleback-dog-harness)

[image]